# How to replace my username in a script with variable

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to make an install script for my home PC and I want to make it more flexible.

How to replace my username with current user variable?

Example: download to: /home/THISUSER/Downloads/

Comment: You can use the variable `$HOME` for the home, and `$USER` for the user :)

Comment: @dadexix86 you may as well post an answer. This question is far too cheap to waste time in the comments

Comment: @Serg yes, but I am almost sure that it is a duplicate, and I am looking for the original one :)

Comment: Note that the Downloads folder only exists on English systems. They can get renamed if the user chose a different localization.

Comment: download was only for example. Files will be deleted after install. But thanks for the usefull info

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the variable `$HOME` for the home, and `$USER` for the user.

Your example can then be `$HOME/Downloads` or `/home/$USER/Downloads`.

Comment: Not all systems use /home for home directories, so the best practice is to use $HOME if you are referencing the home directory.

Comment: @asmeurer we only deal with Ubuntu and official derivatives.  What default version does not use /home?

Comment: Just because this site is only about Ubuntu doesn't mean you should avoid writing portable code and using best practices.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to do this you should use ...

```
more ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="/discworld/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="/discworld/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="/discworld/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="/discworld/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="/discworld/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="/discworld/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="/discworld/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="/discworld/Videos"
```

so that would be

```
echo $(xdg-user-dir DOWNLOAD)
```

and it will show the default download location (in my case `/discworld/Downloads`). Works  for all of these words. Like ...

```
echo $(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)
```

Comment: This is the *real* universal way, always works :)

Comment: Just `xdg-user-dir DOWNLOAD` if you want to print it. :P

Comment: What does `more` do when `!isatty(stdin)`?

Comment: @JacobVlijm There are systems where xdg-user-dirs isn't installed. Probably less so under Ubuntu, but it's definitely less universal than using $HOME and $USER.

Comment: @jazzpi Since we are on Ask *Ubuntu*, the above user's directories within the scope of the question are universal, while ` $HOME/Downloads` definitely is not.

Comment: @jazzpi can you give examples of those operating systems?

Comment: @JacobVlijm How so? `xdg-user-dirs` isn't necessarily available on a Ubuntu system. I'm not saying that it's a bad answer, but it's not a *universal* one. `$HOME/Downloads` is not universal but `$HOME` is. If `xdg-user-dirs` is installed it's obviously preferrable.

Comment: @Rinzwind For example a minimal Arch Linux install. I don't have a Ubuntu Server install but since anything with `xdg` in its name is related to graphical environments using the X server, I can imagine that it wouldn't be present there.

Comment: @jazzpi name 1 official Ubuntu flavour that has no `xdg-user-dirs` . Arch is no Ubuntu.

Comment: @JacobVlijm As I said, probably Ubuntu Server. Or any Ubuntu that I ran `sudo apt-get remove xdg-user-dirs` on.

Comment: Sure, if I remove `python`, I have a non- working system. We may assume here we are working with a default Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use tilde (~) as the home directory, so something like:

```
cd ~/Downloads/
```

Would be the same as

```
cd /home/username/Downloads/
```

This would only work for the current logged in user